# Netlogo To randomly select one of 3 procedures

Tags: procedure, netlogo

How do I randomly select one of 3 procedures?

Please see below:

```
to move
   ifelse random-float 100 < 70 
   [move-forward]
   [move-left move-right move-back] ;; To randomly select one of these 3 procedures to execute.
end
```

Thank you. I am quite unfamiliar with the syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NetLogo 6:

```
run one-of (list [-> move-left]
                 [-> move-right]
                 [-> move-back])
```

NetLogo 5:

```
run one-of (list task move-left
                 task move-right
                 task move-back)
```

Comment: Since version 6.0 of netlogoth use of 'tasks' is no longer available, is there a way to do this the same way but then without tasks?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include both NetLogo 6 and NetLogo 5 versions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not too much elegant, but that may work:

```
to move
  ifelse random-float 100 < 70 
  [move-forward]
  [let n random 3
    ifelse n = 0
    [move-left]
    [ifelse n = 1
      [move-right]
      [move-back]]]
end
```